# Strict units in A-infinity algebras

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, a-infinity-algebras

In Kontsevich-Soibelman's paper "Notes on $A_\infty$-algebras, $A_\infty$-categories and non-commutative geometry", $A_\infty$-algebras with *strict* units are defined so units act trivially on higher operations $\omega \circ_i 1 = 0$. It seems natural to me, but is there a reason for that?

Comment: What kind of reason are you looking for?